# BufferedInputStream on Android - Invalid Argument Error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-io, android-vpn-service

I'm currently working on a project which uses Android's `VpnService`. During performance testing, I found out that reads are slow from the `FileInputStream` that I created over the `FileDescriptor` returned by `establish()` method. My working code snippet for the same is as shown below.

```
private val vpnIf0 = FileInputStream(fd)

suspend fun readVpnIf0(): IPDatagram = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val bytes = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
    val count = vpnIf0.read(bytes)
    return@withContext IPMarshaller.marshal(bytes, count)
}
```

In an attempt to optimize the code, I wrapped `FileInputStream` in `BufferedInputStream` as follows, keeping everything else the same.

```
private val vpnIf0 = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(fd))
```

But now my read method has stopped working and here's the error which I get.

```
Caught java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.io.FileInputStream.available0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.available(FileInputStream.java:389)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:355)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
```

Just to make sure I was not doing anything incorrect, I tried the exact same read approach with a `.txt` file and a `BufferedInputStream` and it worked like a charm. Upon further inspection of `FileInputStream` implementation, I see some comments near the `available()` method as shown below. To me, it seems like Android uses a slightly modified version than the standard JDK.

```
// BEGIN Android-changed: available() implementation changed from bare native.
public int available() throws IOException {
    // Android-added: close() check before I/O.
    if (closed) {
        throw new IOException("Stream Closed");
    }

    return available0();
}

private native int available0() throws IOException;
// END Android-changed: available() implementation changed from bare native.
```

**Note:** The use case that I have is a `BufferedInputStream` over a `FileInputStream` over a `FileDescriptor` in the Android world. Here, the `FileDescriptor` is a virtual network interface `/dev/tun0`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a gap in my understanding, where wrapping a `BufferedInputStream` over a `FileDescriptor` is not at all possible? I haven't tried the same on a JVM.
2. Or is this a Android specific nuance? In that case, how to overcome this and ensure buffered reads.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This should work. Android has its own Java implementation, but the `available()` implementation you show doesn't seem problematic. Are you sure the FD is still open when you call it?

Comment: @user207421 Yeah it should be. If you see the stack trace, it is going wrong somewhere in the native `available0()` method call.

Comment: That's why I asked.  'Invalid argument' suggests it's closed, and the absence of the IOException means that the `FileInputStream` itself must be still open, with an FD that got closed by some other means.

Comment: @user207421 Let me have a look at it!

Comment: @user207421 - The `fd` is open. `Log.i(tag, "FD state: ${fd.valid()}")` prints `true` just before I attempt to read.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a bug. But if BUFFER_SIZE is reasonable, say 8K or more,  there is no advantage to using a buffered stream.

Comment: @user207421 I'm using a 16K buffer for reading.

Comment: @user207421 Btw, where can I find the native implementation of this method? I wanted to have a look at the source code for this.

Comment: No idea where you will find Android native method source code, but it's only going to be essentially a one-liner that calls `ioctl()` with `FIONREAD` followed by some error mapping. Anyway the good news is that as you are using a 16K buffer you can throw away the `BufferedInputStream` and revert to your working code.

Comment: @user207421 But the issue with that is read() will only return one IP packet at a time. And in most of the cases, the packet is much more smaller than 16KiB and the buffer is not fully utilized.

Comment: Well bad luck, you don't have any choice until they fix their bug in `available()`.

Comment: And if these are UDP datagrams, you're only suppose to get one at a time, and a working `BufferedInputStream` would work exactly the same way.

Comment: @user207421 These will be Layer 3 IP packets, so it would be TCP or UDP. Thank you for the insights though! Trying to optimize other parts of the code.

Comment: If they are TCP segment you will get whatever is present in the socket receive buffer. If they are UDP datagrams you will get one. Using an application buffer size of 16K trumps any possible need for a `BufferedInputStream`, as I've already stated, and as `BufferedInputStream.read()` calls the non-working `available()` method where `FileInputStream.read()` doesn't, you have to use the latter anyway.